# Android: Some apps are not available for Tablets on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

Since it came out the new developer console and the new PlayStore I have some problems like the one mentioned in the topic.

Lately my app is not visible from the tablets even if it was before.

But the console tells me:

```
Supported Devices: 2665
Excluded Devices: 0
```

So I have to think that there is no problem, but why this app is not available when you try to search it on PlayStore from tablets?

As suggested on the forums I put the following code in the manifest:

```
<supports-screens
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Is there a safe way to support all tablets without exceptions?

Comment: From which tablet you have checked ???

Comment: Could you post your manifest to ?

Comment: @ZouZou the rest of manifest is composed by activities android version and permissions

Comment: I would see the tag `<uses-sdk>`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your **uses-sdk** includes the **android:targetSdkVersion** with a value of **11** or higher.
Seems Google added this criteria (without telling anyone directly) when they release the new version of Google Play.

The [Tablet App Quality Checklist](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#google-play) under **8. Target Android versions properly**
now states that

> a. targetSdkVersion is declared with value 11 or higher (14 or higher is recommended)

It seems that this only applies to updates/new-releases as previous apps which lack this seems unaffected. The Developer Console also doesn't seem to be "aware" of this requirement as it clearly states xlarge devices as supported.